# Media Query Syntax Issue

Tags: html, css, syntax, media-queries

I'm not a strong coder, and am having a media queries syntax issue I could really use some help with. I found a [query specifically for high dpi devices](https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599), and want to use it to display a different graphic if the devices dpi is high enough. However I also want this query to work only if the screen is below a specific max-width, and that's what I'm having trouble adding to it. Below is what I've been trying (so last line is added by me), but it isn’t working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```css
@media 
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
 only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
 only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi),
    and (max-width: 48em)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3)      and (max-width: 48em),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3)      and (max-width: 48em),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10)    and (max-width: 48em),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3)      and (max-width: 48em),
only screen and (             min-resolution: 120dpi)      and (max-width: 48em)
{ 

  /* Bla bla Bla bla**/

}
```

Comment: Bringo! Tested on multiple devices, works like a charm! (I did remove the "," and "(" at the end, assuming they were typos).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, `(max-width: 48em)` is added to the list of scenarios that trigger the query.

You want specify a query with two criteria per scenario, like this:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3) and (max-width: 48em),
       only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10) and (max-width: 48em),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) and (max-width: 48em) 
       {
         // Higher res image here
       }
```

Comment: Worked fine, but I'm assuming HudsonPH's query covers more browsers.

Comment: There is no justice in this world